# jQuery Pajinate: How to ignore hidden list-items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I've a HTML list and want to add a simple pagination with the jQuery Plugin [Pajinate](https://github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate/wiki). That works fine, but I would like Pajinate to ignore the hidden list-items.

For testing, here is the [codesnippet on jsfiddl.net](http://jsfiddle.net/93Xg2/2/) (same as below). The last two list-items should not be displayed and the the num of pages should be 3 instead of 4.

And ideas how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#paging_container3').pajinate({
        items_per_page: 5,
        item_container_id: '.alt_content',
        nav_panel_id: '.alt_page_navigation',
        nav_label_first: '<<',
        nav_label_last: '>>',
        nav_label_prev: '<',
        nav_label_next: '>'
    });
});
</script>

<div id="paging_container3" class="container">
    <h2>Custom List Size</h2>
    <div class="alt_page_navigation"></div>
    <ul class="alt_content">
        <li>
          <p>One</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Two</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Three</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Four</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Five</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Six</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Seven</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Eight</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Nine</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Ten</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Eleven</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Twelve</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Thirteen</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Fourteen</p>
        </li>
        <li style="display: none">
          <p>Fifteen (ignore me)</p>
        </li>
        <li style="display: none">
          <p>Sixteen (ignore me)</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to hide it ?

Comment: @Ricardo Lohmann I've a list with about 200 items. The user is able to filter them. Filtering in this case works like $(".item-with-this-condition").hide();.

Comment: So you have to show the filter code. It will get hidden when it runs, right ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to change anything on the filter code. I just need a way to tell Pajinate it has to ignore the hidden items, even if the filter is not active.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pajinate` but probably it'll count all elements(including hidden) to get paginated. So I suggest you to remove them before.

Comment: if you need to filter the pagination list, likely best to rebuild it each time you filter and build a new pager as well